# Creating multiple routes for one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm having an issue with trying to create two custom routes for one of my controllers. I have these two cases:

1. If someone navigates to /Register, it should use the Members controller and the Index view
2. If someone navigates to /Register/NY, it should use the Members controller and the Register view, and pass the state code as a parameter

Here's what's in my global.asax file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RegisterMap", // Route name
    "Register", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Members", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults    
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Register", // Route name
    "Register/{stateCode}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Members", action = "Register" } // Parameter defaults       
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }    
);
```

If I navigate to /Register/NY, everything works correctly, but if I navigate to just /Register, I get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `"Register/"`, with the ***/***, as the url paramter in the `MapRoute` method? curious.

Comment: @Xander - Just tried it, didn't work.

Comment: could you post all of your routes?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the provided routes as they are. Could you verify that you have an index action in the members controller?

Comment: The only other route I had was the default route. I edited my original post

Comment: @AFinkelstein - I'm an idiot, there was no Index action :) thanks

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrrrr - just delete the post @steven and lets forget this ever happened! ;D

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is correct.

I would verify that you have an Index action within the members controller.

Answer (score 0):

i checked the scenario, it is working fine. plz do verify it.

1. your MembersController class exist in /Controller/ and it extends Controller.
2. MembersController contains a method Index with no arguments or nullable arguments.
3. Index action method do not have HTTPPOST method.[this may cause 404 error.]